# Android detect if Save/Discard screen is being shown after taking the picture

Tags: android, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Cordova camera plugin. When you open the camera, it allows the user to take the picture (**first part**) and then it takes the user to preview photo screen, where user can save or discard the image(**second part**). As per my requirement, I need to know when the user is at second part i.e. he/she is at 'save/discard' screen.

I was able to detect it in iOS via notifications. But I don't have any experience in Android so couldn't figure out a way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Um, how are you working with the camera? Are you working with the camera APIs directly? If so, it is your own "save/discard" screen, so you should know if you are displaying that. If you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, there may not *be* a "save/discard" screen.

Comment: I am using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera to open the camera. I am not directly working with camera API

Comment: here is the java file in case you need to reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am developing a Cordova camera plugin

According to your comment, you are using an existing Cordova camera plugin. I presume that you mean that you are forking that plugin and making changes to it.

That plugin is using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` on Android to take a picture. This delegates to an external camera application. There are hundreds of possible camera applications that could handle the request. That includes pre-installed camera apps from thousands of Android device models.

> I need to know when the user is at second part i.e. he/she is at 'save/discard' screen.

There is no requirement for developers of a camera application to offer the user a "save/discard" screen for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Some may, some may not. For those that do, there is no requirement that they somehow tell other apps that the user is now on the "save/discard" screen.

Hence, there is no way for you to accomplish this, using the existing core logic in that plugin.

Comment: as you presumed, I will be adding the functionality to the plugin myself. I have achieved the goal inn iOS. So wondering if there is any way to have some methods or listeners in native android code to listen to those events(picture taken and picture discarded). Once I have them, I will propgate them to javascript files.

Comment: @harshitgupta: In the camera apps that I have seen that offer this sort of confirmation screen, there seem to be three major possibilities: the user accepts the picture, the user asks to re-take the picture, and the user abandons the attempt to take a picture. The re-take scenario is handled purely within the camera app; you have no way to detect this. Ideally, you should be able to distinguish the other two by the result code passed to `onActivityResult()` (`RESULT_OK` if the user took a picture, `RESULT_CANCELLED` if the user abandoned).

Comment: seems like this is what I am looking for. I will look more into it and get back here. Thank you showing me the direction.

Comment: it didn't help. but seriously, there is a way for this in iOS and not in android. really hard to digest.

Comment: @harshitgupta: Perhaps your device has a buggy camera app. There are many buggy camera apps out there. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`  is simple but unreliable.

Comment: no no, nothings is wrong with "onActivityResult()". its just that my requirement is something that event before onActivityResult() is called. i.e. if the user is on save discard screen. onActivityResult() is called when the user clicks save button.

Comment: @harshitgupta: Oh, that's clearly impossible. As I wrote, there are hundreds of possible camera apps, and none have to offer a confirmation screen, let alone leak knowledge about its operation. Frankly, I would consider what you want to be a security and privacy flaw, as I would not want my camera app telling arbitrary other apps that I am in the middle of taking a picture.